# Not getting the exact value of Shared preference:

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreference in one of my activity and I want to reference the same in another activity and fetch its value. I am doing so as follows:

**Class 1**

**Class Level Variables:**

```
String PREFS_NAME = "Login"; 
SharedPreferences sp;
```

**Setting a value to the SharedPreference**

```
public void savePref(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("loggdin", value);
        edit.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login = " + value,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

**Class 2**

**Class level Variables:**

```
SharedPreferences sp;
String PREFS_NAME = "Login";
```

**In onCreate:** (Please also check the comments)

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        boolean channel = (sp.getBoolean("loggdin", true));// I get the value true or false depending on what I pass as a second argument here, pretty confused! 
        if (channel == true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "true"+channel, 10000).show(); 
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false"+channel, 10000).show(); 
        }
```

Unable to understand where I am going wrong, any hints?

Comment: the second parameter is the default value to get if there is no value in your shared preference that means you are not able to set the boolean value in editor

Comment: Yes as is stated above, I declare the PREFS_NAME in both the classes and assign exactly the same string to it.

Comment: No but if I access the SharedPreference value in the same class that is after setting it, it works exactly fine.

Comment: Toast message in scrren 1? and screen 2? irrespective of all second parameter

Comment: First screen gives me the correct value, the secoond one dont!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to check by debugging the app?

Comment: Hey Ive never used debugging, how do you do that? pardon am new to Android and java.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. Can you please post the code of the whole acativity?

Comment: Hey I fixed it, actually my micromax phone was acting weird, tested on the emulator and it worked superb :) I am still interested to know how debugging works though.

Comment: Its pretty simple. Add breakpoints for lines whose execution you want to verify and then run your app in debug mode by clicking Debug icon from the Launch toolbar in Eclipse. You can toggle breakpoints by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+B. If still not able to debug, you can ask.

Comment: Hey I just tried it mate, its a super duper tool! Will get back if I find difficulty!

Answer (score 0):

Try this my working code..

```
public static boolean getBooleanFromSP(String key) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}//getPWDFromSP()


public static void saveBooleanInSP(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =      preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}//savePWDInSP()
```

Comment: Hey Brijesh it would be really nice of you if you could explain whats wrong in my code.

Comment: Not finding anything wrong with your code , you should debug it only that way you may find problem with code .